# English version of my site is showing up in Google.sv instead of the Swedish version of my site

Tags: google, meta-tags, meta-description, hreflang

I have a website that's in English on example.com and in Swedish on example.com/sv. I have corresponding hreflangs for each language.

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://example.com/">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="sv" href="http://example.com/sv/">
```

I have an English meta description that's displayed on the .com

```
<meta name="description" content="English description...">
```

and a Swedish meta description that's displayed on the .com/sv.

```
<meta name="description" content="Swedish description...">
```

Now, when I check the search result on Google.com, it correctly shows the English meta description, but Google.se also shows the English description with a link to the English site.

I would like Google.se to link to the example.com/sv with the Swedish meta and Google.com to link to example.com with the English one. Is this possible?

Comment: Does google.sv show the English meta-description for the English or for the Swedish pages? If for the English pages: has google.sv indexed your Swedish pages, too? (you can check this with a `site` search)

Comment: @unor The swedish pages are indexed, but still the google.se show mysiteurl.com with the english meta and not the mysiteurl.com/sv with the swedish meta. So it's never .com/sv with english meta or something like that.